# What UTF-8 languages can be displayed 'safe' in HTML without any specific presentational adjustments?

Tags: css, utf-8, internationalization, presentation

For my own CMS I have almost completed a language manager, that will let website owners create new languages on the fly for their website. The thing is -- considering Latin alphabet languages as a default -- at this stage I only want to support languages that don't need specific presentational adjustments, such as `direction: rtl;` for Arabic languages and what have you.

What languages (or groups of languages, such as Latin) generally don't need any of such adjustments, to display properly? Or rather perhaps; what type of languages usually **do** need these types of adjustments? (whichever category is less big to mention :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean by "presentational adjustments". And what it has to do with UTF-8.

The first thing, UTF-8 is just a character encoding, the way to represent Unicode. It is capable of presenting any national character (the only problems could pop-up additional 4-bytes Chinese characters defined by GB18030:2005, but with Unicode 6.0 I believe this will go away).

Another thing: Non-Latin scripts may require adjustments either way - font face and size might need to be changed anyway.

Third thing: You mentioned direction: rtl, which is CSS keyword. The problem is, you should rather use HTML dir attribute to switch directionality - this is in line with [W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/).

Last thing: I wouldn't fix list of RTL languages to say Arabic, Hebrew, Urdu and Persian (Farsi), as there are [other Bi-Di languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Languages_using_bi-directional_text).

In other words, I would consider what to do to allow style and directionality modifications for the end user rather than hard-coding it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Yeah my question is formulated a bit awkward. I meant: because UTF-8 can represent just about every language in the wordl, and then some, I want to limit the choices in my CMS to those that don't necessarily need presentational adjustments.

Comment: For instance: what would happen if you were to answer on StackOverflow in Arabic? I haven't tried it, but I'm pretty confident the text wouldn't be represented `rtl` all of a sudden (but I may well be in for a surprise :). That is a limit I want to stick to in my CMS for now also. I hope I cleared things up with this example.

Comment: Arabic characters have strong directionality - are written Right To Left. This defined by Unicode and I am quite confident that text will actually be written correctly. The purpose of dir attribute is different: it is to adjust web page layout (mirror web page). Of course it has also modifying text boxes semantics. Just read a link I gave in my answer (about W3C Recommendations).

Comment: "In other words, I would consider what to do to allow style and directionality modifications for the end user rather than hard-coding it." Yeah, you're probably right. I'd have to examine the possibilities of different rich text editors first though, to offer my clients a solutions I'm confident about and comfortable with then. And BTW, I wasn't aware that the `dir` attribute was recommended over css's `direction` keyword. So thank you for that.

Comment: "Just read a link I gave in my answer (about W3C Recommendations)." I will. Thanks!